# Click works on disabled menu item in Element.io and event is undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, event-handling

I have a menu tab with menu items where one item must be disabled. I am using [Element](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US). The component is [Navmenu](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu#navmenu)

```
<template>
 <el-menu mode="horizontal" :default-active="route" :router="true">
 <el-menu-item route="/one" index="one">Tab One</el-menu-item>
 <el-submenu index="additional">
 <el-menu-item index="disableMe" disabled> Disable Me </el-menu-item>
 </el-submenu>
</template>
```

The click event works on the 'Disable Me', even though it has be disabled so I tried to capture the event and prevent the default action.

```
  <el-menu-item index="disableMe" disabled v-on:click.self.prevent> Disable Me </el-menu-item>
```

An error occurs that is event `preventdefault()` not defined.

I tried another option, i.e. I added click to capture the event and later call `preventdefault()` function.

```
 <el-menu-item index="disableMe" @click="disabled"> Disable Me </el-menu-item>

  disabled (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }
```

The event.preventDefault() is not defined error

I tried another option, i.e. I added click to capture event and passed the event explicitly

```
  <el-menu-item index="disableMe" @click="disabled('disabling element', $event)"> Disable Me </el-menu-item>

  disabled (msg, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }
```

The event.preventDefault() is not defined error.

Is there any other work around or am I doing something wrong here?

Edit:  I had to update the npm library and it worked. * sigh *

Answer (score 0):

I have met with a similar question. And I found that the version I was using is element 2.0.11 while I was reading the document for 2.4.11. Unfortunately, there is no disable property in 2.0.11 version in a sidebar. If you can update the element, I think you can solve the problem. If you want to write your own event, I think you need to read the source code about the component first. I hope it is helpful.